# How does Angular router know where to route URLs to when they are buried in dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, module, ngroute

In the [Sample Angular App](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app)

For example, in one [obscure module of the app, there is a route](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/app/projectsinfo/projectsinfo.js#L3) like:

```
$routeProvider.when('/projectsinfo', {
    templateUrl:'projectsinfo/list.tpl.html',
    controller:'ProjectsInfoListCtrl',
    resolve:{
      projects:['Projects', function(Projects){
        return Projects.all();
      }]
    }
  });
```

I have two questions about this:

1) How does Angular locate this path and put it together with its registry of other paths? Is it because the same `$routeProvider` is used?
2) Is this a bad coding practice - i.e. putting routes in different modules? Are there advantages to doing it?

I would love if someone could enlighten me. I am just starting out with Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Even though a provider (like routeProvider) can be used in multiple modules (and those modules are dependent on each other), the provider is instantiated only once, which makes is a singleton. So in every module you are dealing with the same provider. Since every module has its own config phase, you can configure it again and in this case the registration ends up in the same registry (internally).

So to answer your first question: yes, it is because the same $routeProvider is used.

To answer your second question: I am a little hesitant to say that this is good coding practice because I haven't seen this pattern anywhere else. But there is definitely potential in it, because you can create modules that are about a set of functionality including pages. It makes sense to define routes for that set of functionality inside that module, so all knowledge about it lives inside that module.

The downside is that urls can be overwritten in other modules that are loaded later on, especially by the main app that takes these modules as dependencies.

```
angular.module('app',['a','b']);
```

So if in module 'a' you have '/home' defined as route as well as in 'app', the one defined in 'app' will overwrite the one defined in 'a'.